How could people have used ints to store C pointers historically?
I am currently reading Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective by Bryant and O'Hallaron. They remark that

For example, many programmers historically assumed that an object declared as type int could be used to store a pointer. This works fine for most 32-bit programs, but it leads to problems for 64-bit programs.

I am trying to understand how programmers could have done such a thing in the first place. An int is generally signed, so wouldn't storing a pointer of value greater than 2^31 have caused type-casting and errors? This is mostly a historical curiosity I guess, but I figured I'd ask nevertheless.

C was sloppier in 1970s and 1980s; it allowed that sort of thing back then.  Since C was standardized in 1989/1990, such abuses are harder to perpetrate.  During this millennium, it requires major fighting with the compiler via casts to achieve the dubious effects.

Find the Lions book on the Unix V6 kernel to see what early C looked like.

Understood, thank you! Just to confirm, is my suspicion then correct: this practice could have resulted in issues for pointers with values >2^31-1 (the upper bound on positive values for [signed] ints)? @JonathanLeffler

When people stored pointers in ints, computers typically had 16Mb of RAM and nobody would have imagined to have 64 bit pointers anytime soon.

Potentially, yes.  Such pointers would have been negative.  But don't forget that computers had but a few megabytes of memory back then, and “few” means single digits, if not less.  The disk drives did not reach gigabytes either.

It'd "work" the same way as if you store a too-large unsigned int into an int. In practice (platforms/C standards where int is two's complement, not that you should do it) you'll have an negative integer. If you convert it back to an int, you'll end up with the same value (again, in practice, not that people should rely on code like this). You just need pointers that aren't larger than int.

Others have said "how", I'll say "why". C was seen as "one step above assembly language" back then. Also, CPUs were a lot slower than they are now and memory was expensive and compiler optimizers weren't as sophisticated. So C programmers did a lot of "hand optimization" of code (i++; might generate fewer assembly languages instructions than i = i + 1;) to squeeze the most out of what they had. Also, be aware that the C language itself was more primitive; for example there was no "union". The "int / pointer" equivalence was sometimes used to get a degree of abstract data storage.

You only have half a megabyte of RAM. Why would a pointer be bigger than 2^31?

Perhaps you should ask this on SE Retrocomputing.

Not all systems with small memories (small seen from today) address the memory from zero to its upper limit, and memory is not necessarily continuous. Some memory ranges can be in the topmost range, resulting in a set topmost bit.

Firstly, it wouldn't cause much issues unless people did something funny with these ints. E.g. let's say I've got pointers 0xFFFF0000 and 0xFFFF0010 and I cast them to ints. I'll get -65536 and -65520. If I can them back to pointers I'll get back the same pointers. If I substract second from first, I'll get 16 for pointers and for int. If I compare them, I'll get first less than second for poiners and for ints - however this one is fragile; 0x7FFF0000 and 0x81000000 would compare wrong. In short, at least roundtripping from pointer to int to pointer works just fine when pointers and ints are the same width.
Secondly, pretty sure they meant both int and unsigned int (width is the defining characteristic, not sign), and often pointers were stored as unsigned ints which worked flawlessly on 32 bit.

I take your point that comparison doesn’t work, thank you! By the way, and just before I accept, can you explain how casting results in those values? I’m just naively taking those bit patterns as 2’s complement representations of integers but getting wildly different numbers than you. For example, 0xFFFF000 represents -2^32 after inverting and adding 1 to get the magnitude. Does the C standard demand something else?

@EE18: FFFF0000 is not 2^−32. To see this, observe that FFFFFFFF is −1, FFFFFFFE is −2, FFFFFFFC is −4, FFFFFFF8 is −8, FFFFFFF0 is −16, and so on. When you get to FFFF0000, you will see it is −65,536.

@EE18 C standard, until C23 I think, didn't actually define a particular representation of negative numbers (which is why signed integer overflow was a UB). It is always binary completent in practice of course. In binary completement, you can negate a number by inverting and adding 1, you are right. So 0xFFFF0000(32 bit) negated is 0xFFFF, add 1 and you get 0x10000 == 65536

My apologies to both of you—I don’t know why I chose 2^32 instead of 2^16. Brain fart counting the number of bits in four hex digits I guess. But in the example you mention would compare wrong, can you elaborate on why? You seem to have only given 7 rather than 8 hex digits so I’m not sure what is intended.

sure. Intention was to contrast positive and negative parts of integer space: 0x7FFF0000 and 0x81000000. First compares less than second in unsigned, but when converted to signed second becomes negative so first would compare larger than second. This could actually lead to some problems if someone would be foolish enough to say, try to iterate over some array spanning through 0x80000000, while using ints instead of pointers (because usual way of doing for (i = begin; i < end; +=i) would not work correctly due to i < end giving wrong results.

Ah, horrid mistake by me. I see now. Thank you again!

When I first started learning C, I struggled to understand how it worked under the hood. So, I decided to learn x86 assembly, and suddenly, everything started to make sense. The key point is that, from the CPU's perspective, both pointers and integers (signed or unsigned) are simply bits residing in memory or registers. A pointer is essentially an unsigned number, containing the memory address (or the 'serial number') of a specific byte. This means you can store a pointer in a register and use it as a signed integer in the next command without any issues (and vice versa). In C, the distinction between signed and unsigned numbers becomes significant when the compiler generates code for arithmetic operations. However, if you store a pointer in a 32-bit int on a 32-bit system, its bits remain unchanged. Here are some examples to illustrate this concept:
// Assume that the system uses 32-bit addressing:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  void * ptr = malloc(32);
  printf("pointer value %p\n", ptr);
  int as_int = (int)ptr; // ok, retains information
  unsigned int as_uint = (unsigned int)ptr; // same
  // You cannot compare as_int and as_uint becase that won't make sense,
  // but after a cast (that, again, does nothing to the bits) it's ok:
  int is_same = (int)as_uint == as_int;
  printf("as_int %d  as_uint %u\n", as_int, as_uint);
  printf("as_int and as_uint are equal? %u\n", is_same);

  // let's write something using the address
  *(int*)as_int = 0xdeadbeef;
  // ... and read it back
  printf("0x%x\n", *(int*)ptr);

  // loses information by throwing away 2 'most significant' bytes
  // (similar to casting a pointer to an `int` on a 64-bit system)
  short as_short = (int)ptr;
  printf("as_short %d\n", as_short);
}

To compile the code above on a 64-bit system with GCC, use -m32 flag, like this:
gcc -m32 test.c -o test
Possible output:
pointer value 0x585151a0
as_int 1481724320  as_uint 1481724320
as_int and as_uint are equal? 1
0xdeadbeef
as_short 20896


"So, I decided to learn x86 assembly, and suddenly, everything started to make sense." Spot-on. Call me extremist, but IMHO there should be a law against teaching people C before teaching them assembly.
